# Subspace problem in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $P=\mathbb{R}[X]$ be the space of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the subset $W\subset P$ given by $$W=\left\{f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_iX^i\mid a_2=0 \right\}.$$

We need to show that $W$ is a vector subspace of $P$. The part the throws me off is the condition that there must be a $0$ coefficient in front of $X^2$. I don't know how to show closed under vector addition or scalar multiplication.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  If you add two polynomials with a zero coefficient of $x^2$ or multiply a polynomial with a zero coefficient of $x^2$ by a scalar, do you get a polynomial with a zero coefficient of $x^2$?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question such that it's more readable. Don't put the question in the title, titles are supposed to be short.

Answer (score 1):

If $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+0\times x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots$, $q(x)=b_0+b_1x+0\times x^2+b_3x^3+\cdots$, and $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, then$$p(x)+q(x)=a_0+b_0+(a_1+b_1)x+0\times x^2+(a_3+b_3)x^3+\cdots$$and$$\lambda\times p(x)=\lambda a_0+(\lambda a_1)x+0\times x^2+(\lambda a_3)x^3+\cdots$$